# How do you get a flat listing of all files in IsolatedStorage?

Tags: c#, .net, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I need to get a list of all files in a given IsolatedStorage folder. There are sub folders off the root of the IsolatedStorage and these need to be included in the list.

The usual System.IO classes can't be used with IsolatedStorage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I've come up with - it works but I'd be interested to see if there are better alternatives:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Linq;

public static class IsolatedStorageFileExtensions
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Recursively gets a list of all files in isolated storage
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Based on <see cref="http://dotnetperls.com/recursively-find-files"/></remarks>
    /// <param name="isolatedStorageFile"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<string> GetAllFilePaths(this IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorageFile)
    {
        // Store results in the file results list
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        // Store a stack of our directories
        Stack<string> stack = new Stack<string>();

        // Add initial directory
        string initialDirectory = "*";
        stack.Push(initialDirectory);

        // Continue while there are directories to process
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            // Get top directory
            string dir = stack.Pop();

            string directoryPath;
            if (dir == "*")
            {
                directoryPath = "*";
            }
            else
            {
                directoryPath = dir + @"\*";
            }

            // Add all files at this directory to the result List
            var filesInCurrentDirectory = isolatedStorageFile.GetFileNames(directoryPath).ToList<string>();

            List<string> filesInCurrentDirectoryWithFolderName = new List<string>();

            // Prefix the filename with the directory name
            foreach (string file in filesInCurrentDirectory)
            {
                filesInCurrentDirectoryWithFolderName.Add(Path.Combine(dir, file));
            }

            result.AddRange(filesInCurrentDirectoryWithFolderName);

            // Add all directories at this directory
            foreach (string directoryName in isolatedStorageFile.GetDirectoryNames(directoryPath))
            {
                stack.Push(directoryName);
            }

        }

        return result;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're genius but also when retrieving the new directories you have to combine their path with the initial directory.

```
// Add all directories at this directory
foreach (string directoryName in isolatedStorageFile.GetDirectoryNames(directoryPath))
{
    stack.Push(Path.Combine(dir,directoryName));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please next time, add this as comment and not as a real answer.